# Javascript / Jquery .html() replaces only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi I am trying to achieve the following:

1) User clicks on file input button, textfield gets replaced with the name of the file

2) User changes the value of the text field, the file contents are erased..

This works fine. However if the user does 1) after he does 2) the values are not showing up in the text field anymore..

This is on Backbone with coffee script..

```
events:
    'change #soundfile': 'soundReceived'
    'change #soundtrack': 'linkInput'


soundReceived: (event) ->
  $('#soundtrack').html($('#soundfile').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", ''))
  @

linkInput:(event) ->
  match = $('#soundtrack').val().match('http://')
  if match
    $('#soundfile').replaceWith($("#soundfile").clone());
    console.log($('#soundfile').val())
  else
    console.log($('#soundfile').val())
    $('#soundtrack').html($('#soundfile').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", ''))
    @
```

***Edit***

```
<div id = "create_form" > 

    <form class="new_plot" name="create_form" id ="new_plot"  data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <div id = "sound_gen">
      <span>
      <textarea class="input" id="soundtrack" name="name" rows="1"  onClick="if(this.value == 'Soundtrack: upload mp3 file') { this.value = ''; }">Soundtrack: upload mp3 file</textarea> 
      </span>
          <img id = "btn_upload" src ="/assets/upload_icon.png"></img>
          <input name="soundtrack" type="file" id ="soundfile"/>
      <span class ="generate">
      <input class="blue_button btn_generate" name="commit" type="submit" value="create" id ="plot_subm"/>
      </span>
  </div>
    </form>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) to change the value of a form element, not [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2), for example:

```
soundReceived: (event) ->
  $('#soundtrack').val($('#soundfile').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", ''))
  @
```

Trying to change the value of an `<input type="file">` through a script is generally pointless (for hopefully obvious reasons) but you can try with `.val(...)` if you'd like.

Stripped down demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5n6aZ/

Also, you should probably be using a [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.placeholder) attribute instead of your `onClick` handler in your `<textarea>`.

Comment: great. that works. You are like fairy godmother lol )) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$('#soundtrack').html($('#soundfile').val().replace("C:\\fakepath\\", ''))
```

Should be like this:

```
$('#soundtrack').html($('#soundfile').val(''))
```

So really it was 2 problems:

1. The only value you're allowed to send to a file input is an empty string
2. `$.val()` accepts a single parameter for value, it isn't set like a property

Hope this helps!

Comment: does not work - same effect. Just that first time the contents of "#soundtrack" also show "C:\fakepath\"). When I try to do this operation again (type in some string into "#soundtrack" and then add file again, I won't see the filename).

Comment: @Stpn Can you show me the html so I can test it all together?